# Exception in logging xml esql message broker IIB

Tags: xml, exception, logging, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

My code is working fine for every other type of request. But for one type of request the logdebug function throws exception.

The trace is:

```
ExceptionList
RecoverableException
        File:CHARACTER:/build/slot1/S900_P/src/DataFlowEngine/MessageServices/ImbDataFlowNode.cpp
        Line:INTEGER:1140
        Function:CHARACTER:ImbDataFlowNode::createExceptionList
        Type:CHARACTER:ComIbmComputeNode
        Name:CHARACTER:SiebelRequestRouter#FCMComposite_1_3
        Label:CHARACTER:SiebelRequestRouter.Compute
        Catalog:CHARACTER:BIPmsgs
        Severity:INTEGER:3
        Number:INTEGER:2230
        Text:CHARACTER:Node throwing exception
        Insert
                Type:INTEGER:14
                Text:CHARACTER:SiebelRequestRouter.Compute
        RecoverableException
                File:CHARACTER:/build/slot1/S900_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbRdl/ImbRdlStatementGroup.cpp
                Line:INTEGER:699
                Function:CHARACTER:SqlStatementGroup::execute
                Type:CHARACTER:
                Name:CHARACTER:
                Label:CHARACTER:
                Catalog:CHARACTER:BIPmsgs
                Severity:INTEGER:3
                Number:INTEGER:2488
                Text:CHARACTER:Error detected, rethrowing
                Insert
                        Type:INTEGER:5
                        Text:CHARACTER:.SiebelRequestRouter_Compute.Main
                Insert
                        Type:INTEGER:5
                        Text:CHARACTER:159.4
                Insert
                        Type:INTEGER:5
                        Text:CHARACTER:logDebug(Environment.Variables.EnvAppName, 'MessageLogger', CAST(ASBITSTREAM(OutputRoot.XMLNSC) AS CHARACTER CCSID 1208));
                ParserException
                        File:CHARACTER:/build/slot1/S900_P/src/MTI/MTIforBroker/GenXmlParser4/ImbXMLNSCParser.cpp
                        Line:INTEGER:971
                        Function:CHARACTER:ImbXMLNSCParser::refreshBitStreamFromElementsCommon
                        Type:CHARACTER:ComIbmMQInputNode
                        Name:CHARACTER:SiebelRequestRouter#FCMComposite_1_1
                        Label:CHARACTER:SiebelRequestRouter.MQ Input
                        Catalog:CHARACTER:BIPmsgs
                        Severity:INTEGER:3
                        Number:INTEGER:5010
                        Text:CHARACTER:XML Writing Errors have occurred
                        RecoverableException
                                File:CHARACTER:/build/slot1/S900_P/src/CommonServices/ImbConverter.cpp
                                Line:INTEGER:372
                                Function:CHARACTER:ImbConverterCPP::internalFromUnicode
                                Type:CHARACTER:
                                Name:CHARACTER:
                                Label:CHARACTER:
                                Catalog:CHARACTER:BIPmsgs
                                Severity:INTEGER:3
                                Number:INTEGER:2136
                                Text:CHARACTER:Unconvertable character
                                Insert
                                        Type:INTEGER:5
                                        Text:CHARACTER:252c
                                Insert
                                        Type:INTEGER:5
                                        Text:CHARACTER: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...
```

I dont know what is this character.

My logdebug function is basically logging of xml which is quite huge.

```
CALL logDebug(Environment.Variables.EnvAppName, 'MessageLogger', CAST(ASBITSTREAM(OutputRoot.XMLNSC) as char CCSID 1208));
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what is your environment. Personally I had a lot of encoding-related bugs when working with Message Broker for Windows. `ASBITSTREAM` function defaults to queue manager's CCSID (coded character set ID). In case of Windows installation it can be some single-byte encoding like CP1252. I suppose you have to pass `CCSID 1208` to `ASBITSTREAM` to make sure the message is serialized in UTF-8. See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05510_.htm